# Can series capacitors reduce guitar cable capacitance without signal loss?

Tags: ac, capacitance, series, reactance

Recently, I was reading about a so-called zero capacitance guitar cable pitched to eliminate resonant frequency shifts when using higher impedance passive guitar pickups. The company claims their solution is not sleight of hand with a buffer to convert the AC signal to low impedance to make cable capacitance less of an issue.

So I was drinking my morning coffee and thunk about how this might work. My first guess is that series capacitance could reduce cable impedance to levels that would retain the pickup resonant frequency profile.

QED

But then I thought about how the AC signal voltage should increase. And then I thought about how the frequency dependent reactance would come into play. And that’s when my 40 year gap since I studied this stuff crept in.

So I wonder what would be the consequence of adding multiple capacitors in series with the low voltage (mV) AC signal arising from ferrous electric guitar strings vibrating in the magnetic field of the passive guitar pickups. How would the input voltage at the guitar amplifier be affected? I imagine it would be altered in a frequency-dependent way but am having trouble intuiting this. My calculations suggest low frequency signals will be attenuated to near zero by the very high reactance, but even at the high frequency range of an electric guitar (a few thousand hz though higher for lower voltage harmonics) the reactance is in the “kOhm” range, much greater than the resistance of the cable iteself.

Comment: It might be smoke and mirror marketing or it might be more genuine but, how can anyone be sure without some details of what it is they they are selling? The capacitance idea sounds like it wouldn't be a clear benefit; it's likely to series resonate the pick-up inductance in an unfavourable way. The devil will be in the details so maybe you can provide some?

Comment: Like a lot of audio/instrument stuff, this smells like snake oil.  That aside, I can't see how series capacitors will increase AC voltage.

Comment: Sounds like a buffered cable, so would be not much different than using active pickups.  Meanwhile, playing my 30 year old guitar through bargain basement cables into my 40 year old tube amp, is more than bright enough, and I have to kill off the high end anyway.

Comment: "Ed can even hear the difference between a guitar plugged into a 5-foot cable and a 10-foot cable." Yep, snake oil.

Comment: At 100pF per meter capacitance, one would have to utilized one Very Very long cable before any difference in signal could be perceived at the amplifier input, let alone the change in resonant frequency between pick-up inductance and cable capacitance.  Hi-Fi wizards runs their sound quality appraisal through so much wishful thinking it’s no longer science :)

Comment: @FredCailloux How much is very long? Assuming 100pF per meter, 10 meters is 1nF, and guitar pickup could have 20kohm output impedance. That's 8 kHz cutoff already. Surely you can hear the difference in the timbre between 1 meter and 10 meter cable as the difference is if the cut off starts at 80 kHz and 8 kHz. No Hi-Fi wizardy, just science.

Comment: 1.5m cable vs..3m cable sure is audible.. Not because of the RC lowpass but because of the LC resonance shift. A series capacitor won't fix this and introduce other problems like its own resonances and lack of bass end. the way to fix it is to buffer the signal after the volume pot (e.g. with the "FET cable" or improved versions of it)

Comment: @Justme - I didn't realize that a guitar pickup could have such a high impedance in the order of 20kohms.  After all its just a copper coil. A bit of research I found and am surprised that these sensors have such a high output impedance. Thanks for the education.

Comment: The DC resistance of a Fender Stratocaster coil with 8,000 windings AWG 42 is about 4.7 kOhm. The inductance of a pickup goes anywhere between 2 and 7 Henry. The highest fundamental is about 5 kHz. So where it concerns the signal, the coil can have an impedance of about |Z| = 200kOhm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Series capacitor would just remove DC and low frequencies and pass high frequecies unaltered, except they would still be attenuated by the parallel capacitance of cable, as it would form a capacitive voltage divider, just like resistors form a resistive voltage divider.

But let's look at the cable you ask about.

Cable boasts near-zero (60pF) total capacitance. They say the cable does not buffer or amplify guitar signal with electronics, or change the output impedance of the guitar. It also has direct DC connectivity so the signal and return are directly connected.

Yet, the device needs a battery to work.

Therefore it must be a trick.

And the oldest trick in the book to reduce capacitive loading between signal and return wire is to have a driven shield so the signal has virtually no capacitance to return wire.

It means that the cable might be a triaxial cable, where the unaltered guitar signal goes in the inner conductor and ground return in the outer shield like usual, but the electronics box takes in the same guitar signal that goes into inner conductor and buffers the same signal into the inner shield surrounding the inner conductor.

The buffered signal is just a clone of the original guitar signal, driven to the guard shield with an amplifier. The amplifier has low output impedance and can drive much stronger current to handle the capacitance between guard shield and the signal return shield.

So as the original guitar signal and the buffered guard shield always have (nearly) identical signal, the voltage difference between them is (nearly) zero, there capacitive coupling between guitar signal and guard shield can be ignored, since there is (nearly) no current needed from the guitar signal to charge and discharge the capacitance to any voltage difference.

The amplifier needs to handle the current to charge and discharge the capacitance between guard shield and signal return shield.

In the amplifier end, the guard shield signal is unused and just the original guitar signal and return ground shield are used on the 6.3mm plug.

So largely the 60pF capacitance that the guitar needs to drive is the length of cable between guitar plug and the amplifier box input.

It might also be some other cable than triaxial, it really does not matter as long as the guitar signal has very little capacitive coupling to ground due to the buffered guard signal.

Comment: Triax sounds likely +1. It is hilarious that there might be people willing to spend more than $100 on a cable that "DOES NOT BUFFER YOUR GUITAR AND LOWER ITS OUTPUT IMPEDANCE!!!111"  although that has no negative (actually positive) side effects on a guitar signal, whose THD and noise level you can't really *worsen* noticably by even the most antiquated buffer transistors or opamps.

Answer (score 4):

Putting capacitance in series with the cable will form a capacitive divider which will reduce your signal level, if the series capacitance is small enough to lower the total capacitance significantly it will reduce the signal level quite a bit as well. For example, if you use a capacitor that matches the cable capacitance you will halve the capacitance your guitar sees, but also halve the signal your amp sees, and drastically affect the low frequency range.

There are several ways to reduce cable capacitance, one is to use shorter cables. The way to get the shortest cables is to use a [wireless system](https://www.guitarworld.com/features/best-guitar-wireless-systems).

Another way to reduce cable capacitance is to use a different type of cable. Of course if there was a type of cable that combined very low capacitance with the other qualities needed in a guitar cable, such as flexibility and ruggedness, they would use it.

There is the possibility of using balanced twisted pair cable, this is used quite a bit on microphones, but would require a means of transforming the guitar signal to a balanced signal and back, as well as transforming the impedances as balanced cable is low impedance and guitars are usually high impedance. I'm not sure what affect it would have on the guitar signal.

If you're really worried about it, and remember, most of the great guitarists from the early days of electric guitar right up to today have generally just used plain old guitar cables and paid no attention to capacitance, you can use a buffer at the guitar end, that should negate the effects of cable capacitance rather well.

Another option is to use a [treble booster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treble_booster), which is a relatively popular effect.